# Override Javascript Blob implementation for XHR upload

Tags: javascript, upload, blob

Supposing I want to upload a stream of random data from my browser to a remote server. I would use something like

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    // Uploaded.
};

var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});

oReq.send(blob);
```

and repeat this as many times as I have chunks to upload.

But, what if I wanted to send it using a single XHR request ? Is it possible to override the Blob function and do something like

```
function Blob(arr, options) {
    var chunkSize = 1024;
    MyBlob.prototype.nextChunk(function () {
        return arr.splice(0, chunkSize);
    });
}
```

I know that `nextChunk` does not exist, obviously, but maybe there is some interface that can be overridden ? I looked at the [Blob specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and I tried using an [alternative Blob implementation](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js/) (that I modified slightly to force overriding `window.Blob`), but nothing was sent to the server.

Comment: Hi, I think that within a browser you can only consume a stream and not streaming from the browser to the server using XMLHttpRequest.
What about [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to measure the download and upload speed. I have been able to measure speeds up to 1Gbps with the download stream. But Downloading with web sockets gives me speeds around 400Mpbs, obviously due to the overhead of the socket. So I'm afraid that using web sockets I won't be able to measure the achievable upload speed...

Comment: I understand the idea. And I have no answer to give you sorry. Maybe your last comment give matters to other guys to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway :)